# Cannot connect to WiFi network. AssociationFailure on log records

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I have an iPhone 6s. The WiFi connection for the router was OK until today. But now it says "incorrect password" when trying to connect to a secure network and "unable to connect" when trying to an open network. (tested with 2 different wifi routers with 2 different ISPs). Then I tried below steps but no luck.

- resetting router, changing SSID & password
- resetting network settings, hard resetting my mobile
- forgetting network and trying to re-connect
- power recycling my wifi network [as mentioned here](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/31851)

After all of above I connected my iPhone to my mac and collected logs while trying to connect to WiFi. Below logs has been filtered using my wifi SSID : Dialog4G. I can provide all logs if needed. I don't have any idea about iOS development but I think these logs will help someone to identify the root cause as I have done all possible solutions I can .

[This is the router I use](http://www.sztozed.com/en/contents/114/190.html)

```
Jun 16 17:24:17 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {ASSOC*} Completed Apple80211AssociateAsync (-3906 - 0xFFFFF0BE) to Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:17 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Error>: {ASSOC-} Failed to join(-3906 - 0xFFFFF0BE): Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:17 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN, ASSOC*} Auto join association completed (-3906) with current state: Associating, network: Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:17 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Error>: -[WFBlacklistEngine setTriggerForNetworkWithReasonAndState:reason:reasonData:bssid:state:]: Trigger 'AssociationFailure' for 'Dialog4G' (reason=5 reasonData=-3906 state=4)
Jun 16 17:24:17 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN, ASSOC*} Failed to associate with Dialog4G, reason -3906
Jun 16 17:24:18 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN*} __WiFiDeviceManagerFilterNetworks: Filtered networks - Dialog4G Dialog 4G 077
Jun 16 17:24:21 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN, SCAN*} Scanning For Broadcast found: SLT-ADSL-C690F, Dialog4G, Kasun_D
Jun 16 17:24:21 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN*} Filtering scan results due to AJ RSSI threshold: Dialog4G(-89),
Jun 16 17:24:26 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN*} __WiFiDeviceManagerFilterNetworks: Filtered networks - Dialog4G Dialog 4G 077
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN, SCAN*} Scanning Remaining Channels found: SLT-ADSL-C690F, Kasun_D, Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN*} Attempting auto-join for networks in following order: Dialog4G(W, 6)
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: __WiFiDeviceManagerShowApproveToJoinIfAppropriate: Dialog4G not a public/carrier network. Suppressing approve-to-join alert.
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN, ASSOC*} Attempting auto join association of Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: __WiFiManagerApplyNetworkSettings: set for network Dialog4G: Dialog 4G 077
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: __WiFiManagerApplyNetworkSettings: set for network Dialog4G: Automatic
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone rapportd(CoreUtils)[74] <Notice>: SysMon: WiFi state changed: NotConnected -> Connecting, 0x0 < > "Dialog4G"
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone sharingd(CoreUtils)[60] <Notice>: SysMon: WiFi state changed: NotConnected -> Connecting, 0x0 < > "Dialog4G"
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {ASSOC+} Attempting Apple80211AssociateAsync to Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:29 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: Attempting to join WPA network: Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:30 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {ASSOC*} Completed Apple80211AssociateAsync (-3906 - 0xFFFFF0BE) to Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:30 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Error>: {ASSOC-} Failed to join(-3906 - 0xFFFFF0BE): Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:30 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN, ASSOC*} Auto join association completed (-3906) with current state: Associating, network: Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:30 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Error>: -[WFBlacklistEngine setTriggerForNetworkWithReasonAndState:reason:reasonData:bssid:state:]: Trigger 'AssociationFailure' for 'Dialog4G' (reason=5 reasonData=-3906 state=4)
Jun 16 17:24:30 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN, ASSOC*} Failed to associate with Dialog4G, reason -3906
Jun 16 17:24:31 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {AUTOJOIN*} __WiFiDeviceManagerFilterNetworks: Filtered networks - Dialog4G Dialog 4G 077
Jun 16 17:24:34 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: WiFiDeviceManagerAssociateAsync: current (null), assoc Dialog4G, reason User Preference(15)
Jun 16 17:24:34 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: __WiFiManagerApplyNetworkSettings: set for network Dialog4G: Dialog 4G 077
Jun 16 17:24:34 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: __WiFiManagerApplyNetworkSettings: set for network Dialog4G: Automatic
Jun 16 17:24:35 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {ASSOC+} Attempting Apple80211AssociateAsync to Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:35 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: Attempting to join WPA network: **Dialog4G**
Jun 16 17:24:35 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Error>: Failed to associate with Dialog4G: 5
Jun 16 17:24:35 Dineths-iPhone wifid[44] <Notice>: WiFi:[614001275.102425]: Failed to associate with Dialog4G: 5
Jun 16 17:24:35 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: {ASSOC*} Completed Apple80211AssociateAsync (5 - 0x5) to Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:35 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Error>: {ASSOC-} Failed to join(5 - 0x5): Dialog4G
Jun 16 17:24:35 Dineths-iPhone wifid(WiFiPolicy)[44] <Notice>: __WiFiDeviceManagerAsyncQueryLOITypeForLatestLocation_block_invoke_2: LOI Type for 'Dialog4G' = Unknown(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most definitely not the answer you want to hear, but your WiFi died.  It happens.

What was key here is that you attempted to connect to an unsecured network.  One methodology I try to teach to new techs is to take things down to the "lowest common denominator."  Getting connected in a basic state (like with no security) establishes a baseline - there are no other factors that could get in the way like keys, certificates, etc.  If you can't connect there, you have a physical issue.

Next, you tried a different network router.  If the problem exists in two different places, the odds of it being your network go down substantially - like next to improbable.

You did go a bit beyond in your diagnostics, though...so just some feedback for the future:

- resetting the WiFi router is good, but not entirely necessary.  Hypothetically, if you *didn't* own the network you wouldn't be able to reset it.
- changing the SSID and/or password.  Not necessary.  The SSID is just text and the password is just a key.  The radios in the access point (router) and in your iPhone don't care what text characters are being broadcast that identify the network.  Doing the unsecured network addresses this
- forgetting the network and rejoining.  This is excellent.  Doing this in conjunction with the unsecured network will tell you a lot!
- multiple routers and ISPs.  Excellent on the different router (as elaborated above) but it's not necessary to change an ISP.  The radios don't care if you use one ISP over another the same way your car doesn't care if you use one interstate or another.

All in all, excellent diagnostic work, but undesirable diagnosis.  It looks like it's time for an upgrade.

Comment: now my phone is not even turning ON .

Comment: Well, you can’t narrow it down any further, it’s your phone. Sorry for the bad news